# C++11: how to use accumulate / lambda function to calculate the sum of all sizes from a vector of string?

Tags: string, c++11, vector, lambda, accumulate

For a vector of strings, return the sum of each string's size.

I tried to use accumulate, together with a lambda function (Is it the best way of calculating what I want in 1-line?)

Codes are written in wandbox (https://wandbox.org/permlink/YAqXGiwxuGVZkDPT)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
    size_t totalSize = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), [](string s){return s.size();});
    cout << totalSize << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I expect to get a number (9), however, errors are returned:

/opt/wandbox/gcc-head/include/c++/10.0.0/bits/stl_numeric.h:135:39: note:   'std::__cxx11::basic_string' is not derived from 'const __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<_Iterator, _Container>'
  135 |  __init = _GLIBCXX_MOVE_IF_20(__init) + *__first;

I want to know how to fix my codes? Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because you do not use `std::accumulate` properly. Namely, you 1) did not specify the initial value and 2) provided unary predicate instead of a binary. Please check [the docs](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/accumulate).

The proper way to write what you want would be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<string> v = {"abc", "def", "ghi"};
    size_t totalSize = accumulate(v.begin(), v.end(), 0, 
      [](size_t sum, const std::string& str){ return sum + str.size(); });
    cout << totalSize << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Both issues are fixed in this code:

1. `0` is specified as initial value, because `std::accumulate` needs to know where to start, and
2. The lambda now accepts two parameters: accumulated value, and the next element.

Also note how `std::string` is passed by const ref into the lambda, while you passed it by value, which was leading to string copy on each invocation, which is not cool